# style specific unordered list without affecting other ul's

Tags: list, unordered

This is doing my nut in and ruining my weekend.

I found this great expandable jquery vertical navigation menu. The problem is on other pages i have unordered lists and the unordered list style for the jquery vertical menu effects all the other unordered lists and i dont want that.
The html and inline css etc is this..........

```
ul{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#nav {float: left; width: 280px; border-top: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999; border-left: 1px solid #999; margin: 15px 0;}
#nav li a {display: block; padding: 10px 15px; background: #ccc; border-top: 1px solid #eee; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; text-decoration: none; color: #000;}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {background: #999; color: #fff;}
#nav li ul {display: none;}
#nav li ul li a {padding: 10px 25px; background: #ececec; border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;}
      <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

i tried changing the css ul to `#nav ul{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;}` but this doesnt seem to work. please help this me out someone. cheers.

teddy

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you download a JQuery widget or thingamabob, it comes in a folder, with an example on how to use it! But i'm only guessing here that you didn't get this straight from JQuery UI?

In any case, try wrapping your menu into a DIV, with ID = "Nav"...

your other UL's inside your pages should then inherit the default ul style you declare above.

Comment: Thank you very much MaxOvrdrv that was very helpful and i now have it sorted.